# Cannot POST error on registration page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am very new to PHP and databases. I am trying to create a registration page with the following HTML code:

```
<form class="form-register" action="registerUser.php" method="post">
    <input id="username" name= "name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First and last name" required autofocus>
    <input id="username" name= "email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a username" required>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button id="reg" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit">Register Account</button>
</form>
```

And the following PHP Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "rocky123");
  if (!$con) {
      die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
  }

  mysqli_select_db("JEMDental", $con);

  $Email = $_POST['email'];
  $Name = $_POST['name'];
  $Username = $_POST['username'];
  $Password = $_POST['password'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, username, password) VALUES   ('$Email', '$Name', '$Username', '$Password')";

  mysql_query($sql, $con);

  mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

But I keep running into a "Cannot POST /src/registerUser.php" error upon submitting the form. Any ideas why?

EDIT::: Here is my directory hierarchy

[image: Folder hiearchy]

Comment: Also: Remember to change your password later... :)

Comment: your code is failing on quite a few levels here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- could you expand on that statement further?

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php where you'll see the errors. You're also using the same id's in the inputs.

Comment: and not sure if you're running off a host or `file:///`. in any case, I have no idea why one answer got upvoted. I will have to pass on this one, sorry. Ask the new answerer.

Comment: Try setting the `action` attribute in your `<form>` tag to `action="/src/registerUser.php"` just to see what happens.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Gives me the same error :/

Comment: Did you update your server, or just the local copy?

Comment: What web server are you running? Which operating system?

Comment: `action="/DentalCoordination/src/registerUser.php"`  Try that.

Comment: Can you give us a screen shot of the error?

Comment: Are you running Apache?

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the directory/path of `registerUser.php`. You are probably at a different level in your folder scheme.

Comment: my html file & php file are in the same directory. both located in my /src folder

Answer (score -1):

I congratulate you on your PHP journey!

### General HTLM Stuff

There are some spacing and `id` errors in the HTML. Make sure each input you want to submit has a different value for the `name` attribute. Generally, make sure any field HTML element that uses and `id`, has a unique value. Do not put a space after the equal sign. Also, you may want to consider having a `fName` field and a `lName` field, instead of just one `name` field. Yes, that means you would have to alter your database table.

When you get more advanced, but sure to submit a hidden "token" so that you can help defend your site from CSRF (cross-site request forgery) attacks. It lets you know that a submitted form was probably generated from your site.

### Error Message Stuff

Try setting the `action` attribute in your `<form>` tag to `action="/DentalCoordination/src/registerUser.php"` just to see what happens.

If that does not work...

Try setting the `action` attribute in your `<form>` tag to `action="/src/registerUser.php"` just to see what happens.

Make sure your handler file `action="registerUser.php"` is somewhere publicly accessible. Check the file permissions on the directory.

Also, if you have a `<base>` tag in your HTML header, make sure it is not sending any URL to the wrong location. The path `/src/registerUser.php` looks like an absolute path. Try putting `registerUser.php` in an `/src/` directory off of your webroot (/).

**Note**: The above was posted before he posted his directory structure.

If that works, but you do not want handler files in the `/src/` directory, look for a reason thing are being directed there. Hope that helps.

### About That Token ...

I cleaned up the HTML, if that helps. Note the `<input type="hidden">` field. 
Eventually, you can put a hashed / digest value there to help authenticate that a form submitted genuinely came from your server.

```
<form class="form-register" action="registerUser.php" method="post">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First and last name" required autofocus>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a username" required>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="someHashVale">
    <button id="reg" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit">Register Account</button>
</form>
```

### Web Server Stuff

Sometimes there are settings that only allow `*.php` files to handle requests if the `*.php` is in a certain directory. I notice you only have one (1) PHP file in your directory with your `index.html` file. Try adding a file named `index.php`. Try accessing that directly with your browser. If you get the same error message (save, for that it would say GET instead of POST), then will have to adjust your settings so that:

1) ... you can execute `*.php` files.

or

2) ... you can execute `*.php` in that directory.

or

3) You might have to move your website to a directory that is 100% setup to use PHP.

### PHP Stuff

You are not at the point where this is running yet, so there is no need to fix that at that time. However, stay away from the `mysql_*` functions. Go with PHP's PDO.

But, in addition to the token you have to.

1. Sanitize your input.
2. Validate your input.
3. Defend against SQL injection attacks by learning [PHP's PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) API
4. Defend against XSS attacks by using HTML escaping functions properly (when you intend to send user input back to the browser / user agent).

I hope that helps.

Sincerely,

Anthony Rutledge

Comment: @Fred-ii- He is new. One step at a time. :-) First, let's get him to the point that the server gets his request properly. :-)

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge I updated my post with my folder hierarchy. I feel like I had it correctly laid out. Could you please check that? Thanks

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using phpMyAdmin and I have MySQL setup and installed/running. Using a localhost, not a web server

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Oh, I totally agree. But the thing is, many look up to higher rep'd members and will stick 'em to real good by submitting an answer that would only cover parts of a solution. I've been there and it's not funny. People expect a lot from higher rep members. I could go on with this, but it would be off-topic somewhat.